# Display Column in pandas based on criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe called df. I am currently trying to get a count of how many airports have an elevation called below sea level. I am basing the criteria off of two columns. one is called type which gives the airport type(such as helipad, large airport etc) and another column called elevation_ft which gives me the elevation. I currently have the following code which was supposed to just give me all the rows that follows the criteria. The following code keeps giving me an error

```
airports_df.loc[(airports_df['type']) & (airports_df['elevation_ft'] < 0)]
```

The second code is supposed to give me a count based off of the type for example

```
Small_Airport  5
Helipad        2
Large_Airport  20
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: `airports_df.loc[airports_df['elevation_ft'] < 0, "type"].value_counts()?`

Comment: That worked thank you very much!